# Is there such a thing as "discarding" an input wire to a "CD"-Markov morphism

Tags: pr.probability, ct.category-theory, string-diagrams

[A CD category is a copy-discard category](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.00322.pdf) and some (maybe all) Markov categories are copy-discard categories.  I have been playing around with discarding an output wire by marginalization.  Now I want to move on to something seemingly a bit weird.  I want to discard an input wire by doing something just like marginalization.  Is this possible? If so, how do you define it?  What is the diagram that would express this?  I have tried to picture this below and I put in a big arrow to indicate the "direction" of the morphism:

[image]